# Building backward compatible binaries with newer CPU instructions support

Tags: c, gcc, x86, compiler-optimization, inline-assembly

What is the best way to implement multiple versions of the same function that uses a specific CPU instructions if available (tested at run time), or falls back to a slower implementation if not?

For example, x86 BMI2 provides a very useful [PDEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_Manipulation_Instruction_Sets#Parallel_bit_deposit_and_extract) instruction. How would I write a C code such that it tests BMI2 availability of the executing CPU on startup, and uses one of the two implementations -- one that uses `_pdep_u64` call (available with `-mbmi2`), and another that does bit manipulation "by hand" using C code. Are there any built-in support for such cases?  How would I make GCC compile for older arch while providing access to the newer intrinsic?  I suspect execution is faster if the function is invoked via a global function pointer, rather than an if/else every time?

Comment: See how OS kernel does this (hint: for x86 it's a huge number of features based on what _cpuid_ instruction returns).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can declare a function pointer and point it to the correct version at program startup by calling `cpuid` to determine the current architecture

But it's better to utilize support from many modern compilers. Intel's ICC has [automatic function dispatching](https://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=49#121) to select the optimized version for each architecture long ago. I don't know the details but looks like it only applies to Intel's libraries. Besides it only dispatches to the efficient version on Intel CPUs, hence would be [unfair to other manufacturers](https://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=49#49). There are many patches and workarounds for that in [*Agner`s CPU blog*](https://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=121)

Later a feature called [Function Multiversioning](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FunctionMultiVersioning) was introduced in [GCC 4.8](https://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=49#130). It adds the `target` attribute that you'll declare on each version of your function

```
__attribute__ ((target ("sse4.2")))
int foo() { return 1; }

__attribute__ ((target ("arch=atom")))
int foo() { return 2; }

int main() {
    int (*p)() = &foo;
    return foo() + p();
}
```

That duplicates a lot of code and is cumbersome so GCC 6 added `target_clones` that tells GCC to compile a function to multiple clones. For example `__attribute__((target_clones("avx2","arch=atom","default"))) void foo() {}` will create 3 different `foo` versions. More information about them can be found in [GCC's documentation about function attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html)

The syntax was then adopted by [Clang](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39958935/995714) and [ICC](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-c-compiler/topic/393631). Performance can even be better than a global function pointer because the [**function symbols can be resolved at process loading time**](https://jasoncc.github.io/gnu_gcc_glibc/gnu-ifunc.html) instead of runtime. It's one of the reasons [Intel's Clear Linux](https://clearlinux.org/news-blogs/transparent-use-library-packages-optimized-intel-architecture) runs [so fast](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=GCC-Clear-make-fmv-patch). ICC may also create [multiple versions of a single loop](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/getting-the-most-out-of-your-intel-compiler-with-the-new-optimization-reports) during auto-vectorization

- [Function multi-versioning in GCC 6](https://lwn.net/Articles/691932/)
- [Function Multi-Versioning](https://docs.01.org/clearlinux/latest/tutorials/fmv.html)
- [The - surprisingly limited - usefulness of function multiversioning in GCC](https://hannes.hauswedell.net/post/2017/12/09/fmv/)
- [Generate code for multiple SIMD architectures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44479069/995714)

Here's an example from [The one with multi-versioning (Part II)](https://extensa.tech/blog/multi-versioning-problem-part2/) along with its [demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ1QBXYsg4ByKQGY8tZK2VYA1OO0BhZAoL5UZ7OIAMAQR16DRzKYtWbegvZOrpK6%2BoYmZpbWxHrAgS5uYZ7eUTaseABG8a4JIe7hXpHICMR0dtoOuaEeERYAbpjIRMTZQYk1hRa0ALbd/jG0AHQIrS7WzAR4yMZotNbG/gBs3AD6BMbSAJIAKgBim9gAMgAiKwybAFrYK9IAmtvYDN7HxtzGAFTGnI6Sb5/fvzMsjGBAmUxmdHm/mMACVsAAFbDObbPYySRwYxxAtogsHTOqoPDoYy7PCsVjSZRUKiYYgQZT%2BAAca0%2BGUIVDwmFY6FIxgZ9GWa2MCjwAC9MABKUwAdmBzmMCohc3WxWYxE%2B8ORDxhADlUVJJAB1YWi5DijLEcUKUUAT1onJmJVFzGtZuMFtFfWMAHdjARLcg9JywGADdiXIrjMxlERjAAHCYEWm0BhizovaLsWgQTXbbU6iXh%2BWK6OxuP%2B1FsggcrnoItOACcpdQxkwtHQ8IrZheVZr3NMMmFaaLkaCke9CDJmAg5eIA%2Bk8cTydT4pSrfbneIUvEsrHkcV3Uw3WQcZtM/9vNz%2Bd5CYISeIKbThe0cr3%2B/jXZk3cXd%2BXw5fb4yscbTSsBCQuHo6S0F40JxqgcZoMoAqrBkDKsJMtArN0yjoXgarFCsrCoPB9JLKs6zoBMzDbru4ENsQmAEKotDGCsKyoWSGErHBCEqPQ5IQJRoLPq%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%2BFQsuSLso1YKCZJbcUjQ6yAxgIHecYKCA83zZgAAeSZzMwgxJsUPt%2B3LWP1aYw3I/Q/mBdW1XFb5NcSiL5KoMgEBbHsBwnGclzXHcDwMGXkakuSlLUrSEBqyFGw7PsRynOcVw3PcjzD4quXkZ9aUB%2BX1joCAIANE0JCRLTRMM7DmFk8QFMBBUxgswAao0zQjoqz%2BvyQgxxsoChuRkZgyAdaaVlFZWgNleJIXRg5TiegsI4VOmoNyRF4K8gNOAyBdkYGHScogvCyDzpxjDKBMu4lAKNURvMZsUhFiP2hsYROn8T5bhlNTd8zZhQKXWN%2Bfeh9iilFoKgQ%2Bk5gBuU2qgQwjMVJEWAYfIR3pxbv3fJtba2gXgs0GCzKeQVay8k7vPHuS9%2B6rwYLyOEiJkTrw4TGFs1h4Koj4SgEoZQRF4DESsCRUir4yLbgnEACilFs3fFGWxBVVBgjoI4mw/CXFCMPugCJ0iWDWEiE4gRriQB9HJHgBQjQ6DoC%2BhUCA9i4zGBdlwtUBAJSDGwUE9h%2B5oSEFTsVRJxBIksXsMYRw25tC7Fnl3Bevdl4D0eB8WECIkQon%2BJiYw81wntMZnMr4Pw3jzIBG8RObV1qKhxA2RseArbNQIC0rpPS9mNkbMHegocwySCumnAcV1iQAFlpDzS%2BldX2el6H6EGDzQ8oUTkKDIYHRsXI8kXLBYHa5Ms7kPMTjqeargvkl0kLyTRALJTKKAk9SusLblyykFdQwxcfmbTIT9ZwGgJRCBABoK6GhSC0HpY4JlwiNDmBWguJQqh1ADm0JwJlBBWU0tpQne5gxpTcG4Jwe52hJCLG0NKRw0pFh0o0NwJlLKNBstIBypladHCkBFbqmlpA4CwCQGgbocYpxkAoCVW19qQDAABKQDk6FaRpynqK0gbIea33pUK0gNrDz0AAPK0FYDaP1WARaiHYHGvADEYYNDTma0g2dGgxk0CG/wXI/XpAtGqG05gMB5uFTEbowbzU0HoEwNgHAeD8EEMIUQKBuVCEyGnSAtL4KMwzS7CN2hyn727BIL8MhOAhryewGGdBKBtnQOWww3QWWcCze2Q4ehMA6mUN0DItJBBwRFIzVdB6N2kFPYQK%2BO7oL7sPcezdc7X5XwYNwi967BCvoXSmbh9690HqPcQH9n7JGXrA1UwDj6QNcFpbytQzbaWsHpYy5lfqOVZ0ZIsF2yxjAO2mN8QYkgxq4EIKNHQm7jDludewOcVGpRcqndIYVoraUQGtagOjtJyCUBtXa%2BjKB21uu%2BMaz194fUZD9QG0ttbQ3cfDQQKNMa41HhEMAJNmb8CpsmOmv12bkC5vkwW1Dmbi3tNvuWrA8n/R4BrRoIVtL62MBYEmltAh0Uic7Sx7tGRe3i31eWK%2BQ6R1jpsBO7lM7DVcjfYuiAy6v1XuXTB4Dz7r2oDPVfJLJ7Mu3roKlp9oGX2xb/R%2BqpOWSvzsZuV4gBBCtwZfeBtdV7xh1Ya8%2BhDKgkPwY1ehnVeqsM4bw28AwGmvicEGI4KbZH8DNAFdR2jgnaQCskEx7lbGzUca4zxh1/HuPLdA1MZA6JJAzobB6zi3rKDSczbJoNjmmVhrJip2N2n1OJs0HqnTb79OZsM8Zx75B6CFvM5kSzZaK22erbW5zdBXNNq4LwAQ2ghAaZ87IGQfmAv9uC5Celw7R0u3HeoydmPpDRcUKVxmS72w5d%2BFu9AHXQMXZveeiD36Gds7vbu2Dx6Lu/pq81yDDPBfvoA7ztLLPFDC857wNr9XJdFZAA2LrfLkN9e1Zh%2Bl2HcP4eO2iSbk2GyzYowxkIi2Dv2oFdodbLHNtsrMqQBO0qSNXSuoyaVixpTaEWJIBsDOzNaow5mg1igQDotNY7lD9LJBa9D/Sh3YrSDu09iy7gQA) which is about popcnt but you get the idea

```
__attribute__((target_clones("popcnt","default")))
int runPopcount64_builtin_multiarch_loop(const uint8_t* bitfield, int64_t size, int repeat) {
    int res = 0;
    const uint64_t* data = (const uint64_t*)bitfield;

    for (int r=0; r<repeat; r++)
    for (int i=0; i<size/8; i++) {
        res += popcount64_builtin_multiarch_loop(data[i]);
    }

    return res;
}
```

Note that [`PDEP` and `PEXT` are very slow on current AMD CPUs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36951611/995714) so they should only be enabled on Intel

Comment: `popcount64_builtin_multiarch_loop` is a really weird name for a wrapper around  `__builtin_popcountll`, because it's just a wrapper, not containing a loop.  There's also no need for the wrapper function, it still compiles the same with just `__builtin_popcountll` inside the loop directly.  (You might want to wrap it for portability to non-GNU compilers or whatever for other use-cases, e.g. using `std::bitset<64>::count` .  But that's superfluous to this example that already only works in GNU C / C++, i.e. with gcc or clang.  And compiles with ICC but doesn't make a version with `popcnt`.)

Comment: I have no idea why it was wrapped like that either. Probably the author thought that it's easier to port to other compilers?

Comment: ICC: https://godbolt.org/z/d9BoHF.  Oh, and clang doesn't multiversion either, but it does auto-vectorize with SSE2.  Probably not profitably compared to popcnt, but maybe compared to its scalar fallback bithack.  Anyway, clang10.0 says *unknown attribute 'target_clones'*, so not yet for clang with that compact syntax.

Comment: In the first example, what happens if I just call `foo()` on a platform that does not match either of the attributes?

Comment: @Yurik I haven't checked that but typically you'll have to provide a "default" version

Comment: @Yurik I think the dispatcher will search down the version list and selects the one that has highest priority