# When using x86-64 instructions what is the best way to check for their availability without wiping out their entire performance benefit

Tags: assembly, x86, machine-code, instruction-set, cpuid

I am writing some simple D (DLang) wrapper routines around various x86_64 instructions using inline asm. This is working well, but if I want to have an alternative path for older processors where whatever instruction is missing then the overhead for a check and branch would completely wipe out the benefit of having the opcode available. And I’ve even implemeted caching of the results of tests on the cpuid instruction in a pre-main one-off init routine to set up cpuid query caching/memoization.

I don’t know how other people do it, perhaps fixing up the executable or shared library? Is that possible ? How to switch between instruction available vs unavailable with zero overhead apart from one selection operation at main()?

Otherwise I would have to give out two versions of the library routines, one for older machines, one for newer and hope that users choose to import the right module.

Comment: If ultimate performance is your goal, only check once, then use an alternate set of code depending on the answer. Otherwise, if you're willing to tolerate some conditionals, then check once, set a global variable to test later, and then have diverging code paths at whatever level and/or frequency you find acceptable.

Comment: I think it is typical to set a function pointer at initialization time to a function selected based on CPUID.  If the expected savings is less than an indirect function call, then perhaps it isn't worth using the new instructions.

Comment: Usually you want to do the indirection for a function containing a loop, so you don't have an indirect function call inside an inner loop.  That would often kill the benefit.  Or for instructions that give a small benefit all over the place, like BMI1 / BMI2 (or AVX for scalar FP math), make two builds of the program, one for x86-64 baseline, one for x86-64-v3 (AVX2+FMA+BMI2, i.e. Haswell feature set).

Comment: Thank you. I had considered all of these approaches. Thirty years ago I noticed that JPI C dealt with x87 instructions by patching opcodes to either be real x87 instructions or as some other sort of short (maybe int ?) instruction. Unfortunately I can’t remember the details. But that would be ideal. Something such as ‘andn’ would be the hardest challenge, where the benefit is small, and so easily lost. In some places I have indeed delivered additional library functions that have loops in them, where this makes sense. But this is not a program but a library.

Comment: [Building backward compatible binaries with newer CPU instructions support](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61005492/995714)